# Drawing semi-transparent rectangle wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm trying to draw semi-transparent rectangle without success with wxWidgets 3.0

```
    dc.SetBrush(wxBrush(wxColour(0, 0, 0, 128)));
    dc.DrawRectangle(rect);
```

the result is black colored rectangle
What am I missing?

Comment: does your device/context support alpha-values? (of course depending on your background it should look black/gray-ish)

Comment: How do I check if it supports alpha-values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything using `wxDC` is not going to support alpha at all[*], you need to use [wxGraphicsContext](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_graphics_context.html) and related classes if you want transparency.

---

[*] With the exception of drawing the bitmaps, but not for any other operations.